# Can't align two html5 input range

Tags: css, html

This is my htm5 code. The two input range aren't aligned correctly. How can I align this 2 elements correctly?

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
  <title>Ciao</title></head>
<body>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Indicators</legend>
 <label for="height">Height::</label>
    <span>Short</span>
    <input type="range" id="height" min="0" max="100" name="height" />
    <span>Tall</span><br>
 <label for="salary">Salary::</label>
    <span>Poor</span>
    <input type="range" id="salary" min="0" max="100" name="salary" />
    <span>Rich</span>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: what is correctly how you want to align them

Comment: Do you want them below one another, like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/32o2r10p/)?

Comment: What alignment you want? @user3503186

Comment: @user3503186 OK, I've typed that up as an answer.

Comment: This is from a course (which I am following too) ;-) -- You could have changed the text, at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible solutions are:

- Simply give each preceding label and span widths, or min-widths that are wide enough to fit the longest texts.

  ```css
  label {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 4.5em
  }
  label + span {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 3em;
    text-align: right
  }
  label,
  span,
  input[type='range'],
  br {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1.6
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Indicators</legend>
    <label for="height">Height::</label><span>Short</span>
    <input type="range" id="height" min="0" max="100" name="height" /><span>Tall</span>
    <br/>
    <label for="salary">Salary::</label><span>Poor</span>
    <input type="range" id="salary" min="0" max="100" name="salary" /><span>Rich</span>
  </fieldset>
  ```
- Or, if you don't know beforehand what widths you'll be dealing with, use a table¹. That way, the whole structure will align itself.

  ```css
  .grid {display:table}
  .row {display:table-row; vertical-align:middle}
  .col {display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle}
  .col:nth-of-type(2) {text-align:right; padding-left:.33em}
  ```

  ```html
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Indicators</legend>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="row">
        <span class="col"><label for="height">Height::</label></span>
        <span class="col">Short</span>
        <span class="col"><input type="range" id="height" min="0" max="100" name="height" /></span>
        <span class="col">Tall</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="col"><label for="salary">Salary::</label></span>
        <span class="col">Poor</span>
        <span class="col"><input type="range" id="salary" min="0" max="100" name="salary" /></span>
        <span class="col">Rich</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  ```

Comment: ¹ By a table, I meant a CSS table, obviously. Not a HTML table. Sigh.

Comment: Thank you for the complete response!

Answer (score 2):

Apply `vertical-align: middle` to the range input:

```
input[type='range'] {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Result at [CodePen](https://codepen.io/marina-dev/pen/RxmQwL)